# Firestore: Better understand how security rules work when fetching other document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm really digging Firestore but it's hard to find answer to specific question so here I am. This is just to be sure I understood properly how security rules works :)

Here's my schema:

```
/databases/{database}/documents/Bases/Base1 {
   roles: { // map
      user1: {admin: true}
   },
   Items: { // SubCollection
      item1: {
        name: "Hello World"
      },
      ...n,
      item10: {
        name: "Good Bye World"
      }
   }
}
```

I want my `user1` to fetch all 10 items in Base1. Query is pretty simple `db.collection('Bases').doc('Base1').collection('Items').get()`

But I also want to be sure that user1 is an admin in Base1. So I'm setting this security rules:

```
match /bases/{baseId}/items/{itemId}{
     allow read: if request.auth != null
       && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/bases/$(baseId)).data.roles[request.auth.id].admin == true
}
```

Which works, all good. Here're the questions:

1/ I understand this rules get() will cost me one read (which is very cheap I know). Is it one read per query OR one read per document that needs to be validate? ie. 10 reads in my case.

2/ I assume answer to 1/ is that it'll cost 10 reads. But, as I'm always querying the same $(baseId), cache will kick-in and even if not guarantee, it should drastically reduce the number of charged reads (theorically 1 read even if I'm fetchin 1000 docs)?

Any other advice on how to handle those kind of schemas are welcome. I know read ops are very cheap but I like to understand where I'm going :)

Thanks SO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cost of a `get()` in security rules only applies once per query.  It does not apply per document fetched.

Since you have one query, it will cost one read.

Comment: depending on your needs you *can* use customClaims on the user auth, which costs you zero reads - BUT there's limited space so the claim needs to be simple, like "{admin: true}", or {admin: "managedAccountID"}.  There's extra operational complexity (the claims *have to be* managed by secure node, such as a CloudFunction), butit's entirely secure.